# react native expo undefined is note un object (evaluating navigation.state.params)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-native-flatlist, react-navigation-v5

I have passed data from screen to other screen but when I am trying to access it . it keeps saying undefined is not an object (evaluating navigation.state.params).
I am using N5 . I tried also route.params and it gave me undefined is not an object (evaluating route.params)

```
const EditeScreen = ({ navigation , route}) => {
  // mange textinput height
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(42);
  // manges textInput starts
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState("");
  // onSvaeNote
  function onSaveNote(){
    // navigation.state.params.addNotes({notes})
    route.params.addNotes({notes})
    navigation.goBack();
  }
```

Comment: The `navigation.setParams` method lets you update the params of a screen.

Answer (score 0):

you didn't pass the params in `navigate`, use this:

`navigation.navigate('EditeScreen', {notes: notes})`

then in EditeScreen:

`console.log(navigation.route.params?.notes)`